# How do I restrict a specific SSH user to only connect from a list of machines in a specific file?

Tags: ssh, user-management

I have a virtual machine with ubuntu 16.04 and i'm trying to restrict one user to only be capable of accessing the server through SSH if he's connecting from one fo the machines defined in a new file, /etc/remote-hosts.
I know it's possible to define specific ips in ssh_config but i can't find out how to do it from a new file.